# computerName parameter doesn't always work

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to get the services on a remote server.
When I run the command:

```
get-service -ComputerName server
```

I get the following error:

```
get-service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'server'. This operation might require other privileges.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-service -computerName server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

But when I run the command via Invoke-Command it does work:

```
Invoke-Command -computerName server -ScriptBlock {get-service}
```

Now I guess there isn't a real difference between the two methods, but I'm wondering why this is. I also think the first option is "cleaner".

I did run Enable-PSRemoting

Anyone knows whats going on?